# R: how to change character encoding of a list object

Tags: r, twitter

Just wondering, is there anyway to change character encoding of a R list object?
I have a feeling that I will have to take some multiple steps but I am not sure.
I have googled on the topic but I am not quite getting help from internet.

for instance, consider the following:

```
 library(twitteR)
 library(RJSONIO)


 #Authorize with Twitter's API
 reqURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
 accessURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
 authURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
 consumerKey = "myconsumerkey"
 consumerSecret = "myconsumersecret"
 twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
                         consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                         requestURL=reqURL,
                         accessURL=accessURL,
                         authURL=authURL)
  twitCred$handshake()

  B<-read.csv("BCorp RAW.csv") 
  handles<-B$Twitter.handle
  handles<-na.omit(handles)

  start <- getUser(handles[12])                        

  library(rjson)
  friends.object<- lookupUsers(start$getFriendIDs(), includeNA=TRUE)
  followers.object<-lookupUsers(start$getFollowerIDs(), includeNA=TRUE)
```

the command

```
   followers.object<-lookupUsers(start$getFollowerIDs(), includeNA=TRUE)
```

throws the following error:

```
   Error in twFromJSON(out) : 
   Error: Malformed response from server, was not JSON.
    The most likely cause of this error is Twitter returning a character which
    can't be properly parsed by R. Generally the only remedy is to wait long
    enough for the offending character to disappear from searches (e.g. if
    using searchTwitter()).
```

How can I allow R to preserve the special characters when working with twitter?
hope I edited it nicely...let me know if you want me to edit it again

thank you,

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more your question by providing a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and showing what you expect?

Comment: No. You need to come up with a better example that shows *how* you get the data into R in the first place, because R will by default convert non-ascii characters to UTF-8 (or perhaps `"Unknown"`). Check `Encoding("£")` for instance, which gives `[1] "UTF-8"`.

Comment: is it good? I can't really add real data because my raw data is in .csv file

Comment: Yes, it is good. I think it will be easier for people to work on an answer now.

Comment: Arrrgh.  The edit makes it clear this is really a duplicate of an earlier question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503130/r-working-with-non-latin-twitter-data

Comment: I deleted my old question...sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an `Encoding<-` function that lets you specify encoding of character vectors. List elements might have different encodings within the same list, but all elements in a character vector would have the same encoding. Furthermore, there are 'fileEncoding' and 'encoding' parameters to `read.table` and its `read.*` cousins to allow you to read character data in something other than the default.

```
?Encoding
?read.table
```

There are also a lot of encoding questions answered in the Archives of Rhelp.